# What does "snapping at someone" mean?

Tags: expressions

Please help me understand this. If you're snapping at someone are you then complete losing control and yelling at them or are you just mildly irritated with them?

Comment: "Snapping" at someone isn't the same as totally losing it and yelling. It is just an angry or irritated remark. For example, your child keeps pestering you for a snack and finally you snap at them and say, "Stop it, mommy's busy!"

Comment: Bark is used in a similar sense. And one can say, "Don't bite my head off," when snapped at.